# MongoDB: How to index ranged query inside $or with sort

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

My documents in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59839527ceaa98f14349233a"),
    "entityId" : "10",
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : 1,
    "d" : 1
}
```

My basic queries looks like the following:

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{

    "entityId" : {$in : ["10", "11"]},
    $or : [
        {"a" : {$gt : 2}},
        {"a" : 2, "_id" : {$gt : ObjectId("59839527ceaa98f14349233a")}}
    ]

}).sort({"a" : 1})
```

**Note:** In my other Queries are changing only inside the **$or** and `sort`. So for example the following is another example of my query (only `a` changed to `b`):

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{

    "entityId" : {$in : ["10", "11"]},
    $or : [
        {"b" : {$gt : 2}},
        {"b" : 2, "_id" : {$gt : ObjectId("59839527ceaa98f14349233a")}}
    ]

}).sort({"b" : 1})
```

Currently I'm creating compound indexes as follows:

```
db.getCollection('test').createIndex({"entityId" : 1, "a" : 1, "_id" : 1})
db.getCollection('test').createIndex({"entityId" : 1, "b" : 1, "_id" : 1})
```

When I'm running the first `explain()`query, first index is getting picked just fine, but when I ran on second query I noticed that the first index is getting picked again and the second index is on `rejectedPlan`. What am I doing wrong? Any other better indexes?